# How to remove an infinite animation from a hidden element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

The scenario is like this :

two adjacent element

A & B, overlapping elements(A has absolute positioning) both toggle between CSS transform scale(0) to scale(1) i.e when A is shown B is hidden

I have applied an infinite animation on A (SVG opacity changing grom 0.7-1).

When A is hidden, it's animation still seems to be working.

How to fix this without using display: none

Comment: Add a class on A to add the animation, and remove this class to stop the animation.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove a class with animation for A, and then, if the animation needs to be resumed, return the class with the animation again.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach to do this would be setting `animation: none` or `animation: unset` when A is hidden. You can set up a watcher, [like this one](https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583), to watch for A's property changes and then use an if conditional to check if it has reached its "hidden state." Then you can `document.getElementById('its id').style.animation = unset`

> A bonus tip would be using `else` to set the animation property back to normal once it is "unhidden."